# Generator to home disconnecting utilities side

Tags: generator

Ok I'm dropping my utility service and going fully off grid and want to hook up generator to panel main and remove utility

Comment: Congratulations...and your question is ?

Comment: Unless your utility is charging a lot plus an arm and leg and first born, over the average for power, fuel powered generators get expensive, why they are usually only used when the power goes out.  Solar panels will probably pay for themselves.  Quite a few utilities charge a bit just for having power near the house, so you probably will still have a small utility charge.